# Loader após clicar no link (a)

Tags: javascript

Tenho um site em wordpress e adicionei um plugin para virar webapp com PWA. O problema é como a barra de endereços some, quando o usuário clica em algum link demora um pouco para carregar e a pessoa fica clicando por não saber que a página está carregando.

Encontrei um plugin que cria um loader sempre que a página começa a carregar. No entanto entre o clique em algum link e a página começar a carregar demora um pouco.

Gostaria que logo que a pessoa clicar em algum link (a) o loader já rodar.

Código JS do loader

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 

    jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').delay(0).fadeOut("slow");

    setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 2000);
    function wptime_plugin_remove_preloader() { 
        jQuery('#wptime-plugin-preloader').remove();
    }

});
```

Acredito que `beforeunload` possa ajudar. Como incluir nesse código?

Answer (score -1):

Tente diminuir o tempo em `setTimeout(wptime_plugin_remove_preloader, 2000);` Esse 2000 significa 2000ms ou seja, 2 segundos. Tente colocaruns 500 ( 0.5s )

Comment: Esses 2000 significa o tempo máximo que o loader ficará ativo. Mesmo que a página não esteja totalmente carregada.